# Why is the dismissable alert not being dismissed?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building an app in Angular JS and Bootstrap.

http://numerology.andrewgolightly.com/

Enter some details and look at the results. There is a dismissable alert on the results page that is not being dismissed when the cross is clicked on.

I basically copied the code from http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts-dismissable

```
<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> This number represents who you are at birth and the native traits that you will carry with you through life. The most important number that will be discussed here is your Life Path number. The Life Path describes the nature of this journey through life.
</div>
```

Anyone know why it isn't being dismissed on my site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only included the Bootstrap css, but for the dismissable functionality (and lots of other functionality in Bootstrap) you also need to include the js file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add jquery.js and bootstrap.js

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

in your head section