# Why is the dismissible alert not being dismissed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

***Note:*** Let me start by saying that I'm aware of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21155016/why-is-the-dismissable-alert-not-being-dismissed) but the solution is incomplete and I don't yet have not enough reputation on stackoverflow to comment on it. So, I was left with the only option of creating a duplicate question.

I'm trying to use angularjs and bootstrap (ui-bootstrap) to show a dismissible alert. However, even after including ui-bootstrap-tpls-*.js file (solution suggested on original question) it doesn't seem to work. Although it does work with jquery.

Please check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/61gJ3K?p=preview)

Comment: jquery is required for bootstrap component functionality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to have a dismissible alert without adding extra logic to the controller. I don't even need bootstrap-*-js.
Basically I have an alert with a close button that uses `ng-click` on a `$scope` variable to hide the parent div on `ng-show`. (The controller sets that variable to whether that alert should be initially shown or not.)

```
<div class="alert alert-warning" ng-show="show_alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="show_alert=false">&times;</button>
  <strong>Warning!</strong> Best check yo self, you're not looking too good.
</div>
```

The css classes `alert alert-warning` and `close` are styled by bootstrap.

Check out this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tv7lMI?p=preview) with the above solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between using the native Bootstrap `alert` and angular-ui `alert`.

For the latter, you need to use a `directive`. Here is an example from their website.

```
<div ng-controller="AlertDemoCtrl">
  <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
  <button class='btn btn-default' ng-click="addAlert()">Add Alert</button>
</div>
```

Notice that the element is an `alert`.

You also need to have an Angular module which injects the `ui.bootstrap` module.

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

[Take a look at this plunkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/TJKah7LGlO5UB25DsyOz?p=preview)

Comment: I was hoping that using angular-ui-bootstrap was just a matter of replacing includes. :( I want to keep the alert in the view (and have some bool in the controller that would change the class of some div that would show or hide it with css).

Answer (score 0):

You just imported the bootstrap templates, but not the angular ui bootstrap javascript. The imports for your example should look like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-0.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Furthermore, you don't use an angular app and controller. You need this to make the alerts work. Check the documentation here: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

To close the alert, a `close()` function should be defined. Here is a working example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

    <!-- Will work with jquery (uncomment to try).
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      -->

    <!-- Can't make it to work with angularjs. -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-0.11.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

        app.controller('testCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.alerts = [
                { type: 'danger', msg: 'Warning! Best check yo self, you are not looking too good.' }
            ];

            $scope.closeAlert = function(index) {
                $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
            };
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">

<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Check out the plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/wV1fJO9qAbra7W6J8vz5?p=preview

Comment: I don't think I need more js. According to https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/gh-pages#Instalation the ui-bootstrap-[version].js is the untemplated version (you need to provide a template). The ui-bootstrap-tpls-[version].js has bootstrap-specific templates bundled with directives so it should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue(alerts not being dimissed) I had all the libraries I need imported like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap.css">
<script src="lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```

But later on I found that the order of the library imports is the problem. And I change the import order like the following after that things are working okey.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap.css">
<script src="lib/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I hope this helps. Thank you